# What're the best ways to improve hand-eye coordination/motor skills especially aiming "games"?

Tags: learning, motor, coordination

Aiming in video games, is a prime example of a fine motor skill, & maybe hand-eye coordination "idk? I'm no neuroscientist", but the community of aim practice & improvement "for video games like cs-go for example" is full of pseudo scientific concepts, like muscle memory, with some people recommending sticking on a certain mouse sensitivity "edpi" & never changing it otherwise it'd ruin your "muscle memory", others say that the use of a sensitivity randomizer, or different sensitivities is better, as it forces your brain to focus more, or work harder, or that training the tracking aiming for example on a higher sens will make you more accurate when you play on your normal sens & so on, another thing is advising of training till exhausting or while exhausted claiming that the brain is best able to learn & retain motor skill when exhausted, o using repetition & so on , what does actual research that has been done in this area say about all of this, & what're the best ways to learn, refine & retain a motor skill such as video games aiming?